# How to handle efficiently Google Vision API Client Lib response?

Tags: php, json, google-cloud-platform, response, google-cloud-vision

I'm new to Google Vision API Client Lib

I'm using Vision API Client Lib for PHP to detect text in images, this is my code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Vision\VisionClient;
function object_to_array($object) {
    return (array) $object;
}
$vision = new VisionClient(
['keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents("smartcity-credentials.json"), true)]
);
$img = file_get_contents('img2.jpg');
$image=$vision->image($img,['DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION']);
$result=$vision->annotate($image);
$res=object_to_array($result);
var_dump($res);
?>
```

All I need is using response as an array for handling, but $result returns something likes array of object/object ( sorry because I don't know much of OOP/Object)

Although i convert $result to array $res, but if I use foreach loop

```
foreach ($res as $key=>$value){
    echo $value;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

I get this

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Google\Cloud\Vision\Annotation\Document could not be converted to string

How do we get value (text detected) in above response for using ?.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the methods fullText() and text() in order to access to the detected text, something like this:

```
$document = $annotation->fullText();
$text = $document->text();
```

See the specification of these classes [Annotation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.83.0/vision/annotation) and [Document](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.83.0/vision/annotation/document).

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use `$value` of type `Document` as string with the `echo`.
use `print_r($annotation);` to see what you even get returned.
this [document text detection example](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-fulltext#vision-document-text-detection-php) looks quite alike, notice the nested `foreach` loops there. also see the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.83.0/vision/annotation/document):

```
use Google\Cloud\Vision\VisionClient;

$vision = new VisionClient();
$imageResource = fopen(__DIR__.'/assets/the-constitution.jpg', 'r');
$image = $vision->image($imageResource, ['DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION']);

$annotation = $vision->annotate($image);
$document = $annotation->fullText();

$info = $document->info();
$pages = $document->pages();
$text = $document->text();
```

here's some more [examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/vision/src); in particular the [detect_document_text.php](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/src/detect_document_text.php).